# check with Subscribe ID still activate or not - paypal

Tags: api, paypal

Is there a way to call a function/API to check if a subscribed user is still activate without logging into Paypal.

for example when user has sign up to monthly fee to access website, when the user log's in sends request to paypal to check if the user has paided and has not canceled the subscribe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the GetRecurringPaymentsProfile API?
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getrecurringpaymentsprofiledetails-api-operation-nvp

As long as you have the profile ID, you should be good to go.